# How to get Item ID after Powershell Add-SPOFile

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I am using Powershell to (bulk) `Add-SPOFile` to a Sharepoint Online Doclib. I need to `Set-SPOListItem` properties for the new items in the process, but don't know how to get the Item ID for the newly added file.
 It would be great if `Add-SPOFile` returned an ID, or to be able to pipe from `Add-SPOFile` to `Set-SPOListItem`?
 What is the prescribed solution?

I am reading a CSV file, looping through the 288K entries, uploading a file for each entry, then trying to update the item properties. My code looks like this:

```
Connect-SPOnline -Url https://XXX.sharepoint.com/sites/sedatest -Credentials 'YYY'

$CSVPath = "ZZZ\SODA_CSVData.10.txt"
$SrcPath = "\\MDWeb01\DC\pdf\Released"
$DstFolder = "./SEDA"

$SODAData = import-csv $CSVPath -Delimiter "|"

Foreach ($r in $SODAData)
{
    $UploadFile = "$SrcPath\$($r.Series.Substring(0,1))\$($r.Filename)"
    Write-Host "Uploading $UploadFile"
    Add-SPOFile -Path $UploadFIle -Folder $DstFolder
    $Item = Get-SPOListItem -List SEDA | where {$($_.FileLeafRef) -eq $($r.Filename)}
    Set-SPOListItem -List SEDA -Identity $($Item.Id) -Values @{"LegacyID" = $r.LegacyID}
}
```

View Source on the doc library suggests that "FileLeafRef" is the right property name:

```
"ID": "51",
...
"FileLeafRef": "pf2363010800.pdf",
...
```

Maybe I am not referencing it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there are a couple ways to do this;
The first one I found looks like this:

```
    $Item = Get-SPOListItem -List SEDA -Fields "FileLeafRef" | 
      %{new-object psobject -property  @{Id = $_.Id; Filename = $_["FileLeafRef"]}} | 
      select Id, Filename | where {$_.Filename -eq $($r.Filename)}

    Set-SPOListItem -List SEDA -Identity $($Item.Id) -Values @{"LegacyID" = $r.LegacyID}
```

But the easier way, and the one I deployed (including the FileCreationInfo approach above), looks like this:

```
    $FileStream = New-Object IO.FileStream($SrcFilePath,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
    $FileCreationInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
    $FileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $true
    $FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $FileStream
    $FileCreationInfo.URL = $_.SedaID
    $Upload = $Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)
    $context.Load($Upload)
    $context.Load($Upload.ListItemAllFields)
    $context.ExecuteQuery()

    Set-SPOListItem -List $listTitle -Identity $($Upload.ListItemAllFields.Id) -ContentType "SEDA Document" -Values $Metadata
```

Now I just need to figure out how to add a Check-in Comment during this upload/update without multiplying the version count?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Get-SPListItems` using `where` as your filter, you will be able to find the item ID. For instance:

```
Get-SPOListItems -ListTitle TestList | where {$_.Title -eq "Test Item"}
```

Do let me know if this helps

Comment: Sounds good @George, though I am unable to -match the uploaded filename with either $_.Name or $_.FileLeafRef... is there another variable I should be looking for?

Comment: Depends, is the output giving you a full file path (in which case it would be $_.FullName), or file name e.g. (test.txt), in which case I would have thought it would be $_.Name.

Comment: I am trying to match the filename and extension, i.e. "pf2363010100.pdf". Name, FullName and FileLeafRef all show no values when stepping into the Get-SPOListItem line above...
Any idea where to find the actual property names?

Comment: I've confirmed that "FileLeafRef" is the property that contains the filename I'm looking for, but I am not getting any values for this property when doing the comparison. Am I referencing it improperly?
And can I assign the results to a variable as shown above?

Comment: Try adding the following after your "where" clause: | % { $_.FileLeafRef = $FileNameVariable}

Comment: Note that percent character is an alias for a "for each", as it is possible that you would be selecting multiple items. On the assumption that you're not, the variable will only be set with the single value of obtained using your where clause filter. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This actually made me switch to the following code instead of add-spofile:

```
$Context = Get-SPOContext

#Retrieve list
$List = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("DocLib")
$Context.Load($List)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

#Upload file
Foreach ($File in (dir $folder))
{
$FileStream = New-Object IO.FileStream($File.FullName,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
$FileCreationInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
$FileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $true
$FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $FileStream
$FileCreationInfo.URL = $File.Name
$Upload = $List.RootFolder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)
$Context.Load($Upload)
$Context.Load($Upload.ListItemAllFields)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
}
```

This will give you the ID via `$Upload.ListItemAllFields.Id`